# anchor build failed

Tags: anchor

Compiling getrandom v0.2.10
error: target is not supported, for more information see: https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets
--> src/lib.rs:290:9
|
290 | /         compile_error!("target is not supported, for more information see: 
291 | |                         [https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets"](https://docs.rs/getrandom/#unsupported-targets%22));
| |________________________________________________________________________^

error[E0433]: failed to resolve: use of undeclared crate or module `imp`
--> src/lib.rs:341:9
|
341 |         imp::getrandom_inner(dest)?;
|         ^^^ use of undeclared crate or module `imp`

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0433`.
error: could not compile `getrandom` due to 2 previous errors
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...

Comment: anchor init test --> ok

Comment: just after : anchor build --> failed on getrandom

Comment: cargo 1.70.0   solana-cli 1.16.0  anchor-cli 0.27.0 rustc 1.70.0

Comment: Who has the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently a bug on 1.16.0. Update your solana cli version to 1.14.17 with:

```
[dependencies]
solana-program = "=1.14.17"
```

Once you update the Anchor build should complete successfully.